# Index a query "WHERE a IN (1,2,3) AND b = 4"

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, indexing

I am attempting to apply an index that will speed up one of the slowest queries in my application:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND user_id = 5678;
```

I have an index on `product_id`, `user_id`, and the pair `(product_id, user_id)`. However, the server does not use any of these indexes:

```
+----+-------------+------- +------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys                                                                             | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders | ALL  | index_orders_on_product_id,index_orders_on_user_id,index_orders_on_product_id_and_user_id | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

(There are only 6 rows on development, so whatever, but on production there are about 400k rows, so execution takes about 0.25s, and this query is fired pretty darn often.)

How can I avoid a simple `WHERE` here? I suppose I could send a query for each `product_id`, which would likely be faster than this version, but the number of products could be very high, so if it's doable in one query that would be significantly preferable. This query is generated by Rails, so I'm a bit limited in how much I can restructure the query itself. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do the explain on the actual data?  6 rows is almost always going to just be a full table scan.

Comment: When I run a similar query on my database, the key used is the equivalent to your `product_id`. I'm not sure why your engine isn't using that key...

Comment: Is there any way to add force index? if not, try drop other index related to product_id, just keep index for user_id, see what happened. Or reverse, just make DB have no choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there are so little rows on the database, it does not use indexes, because it's cheaper to do a full scan. Try checking the data on your prod environment and see if it uses one of your indexes.

Also, note that you can eliminate one of your indexes, index_by_product_id, because you already have another index that starts with product_id field.

Comment: Oh, hah. That's a good fact to know about the query optimizer +1 These indexes are new, so currently only exist on development, so I was hoping to have this sorted out before pushing to production. I'll try making a bunch of dummy rows in development and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Matchu You don't have indexes at all on the production table and it has 400k rows?  Well there's your answer right there!

Comment: @Corbin: lolyup. This project started really small where I could be lazy, so today's the day that I finally start going around and fixing things up. Yikes, it's some scary stuff.

Comment: @Matchu I would imagine a full table scan on 400k rows must be quite scary indeed.  I'm actually surprised it only takes .25 seconds

Comment: Aha, there we go. Adding 1k rows to development causes it to use the `product_id` index. Cool, cool, cool. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

For optimal performance **of this particular query** on your production table (with 400k rows), you need a composite index on `{user_id, product_id}`, in **that order**.

Ideally, this would be the *only* index, and you would use InnoDB so the table is [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index). Every additional index incurs a penalty when modifying data, and on top of that [secondary indexes in clustered tables are even more expensive](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) than secondary indexes in heap-based tables.

To understand why `user_id` (and not `product_id`) should be at the leading edge of the index, please take a look at the the [Anatomy of an Index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree). Essentially, since WHERE searches for only one `user_id`, putting it first clusters the related `product_id` values closer in the  index.

*(The `{product_id, user_id}` would also work, but would "scatter" the "target" index nodes less favorably.)*

Comment: @Matchu You are most welcome :) Out of curiosity, did you benchmark my suggestion? What kind of performance are you getting?